# How can I test two elements of one list and if they are equivalent place the element of one list into a new list

Tags: python

I have 3 lists:

```
neighbour = []
scanned = [[],[]]   
localisation = [[],[],[]]
```

I want to test each item in the 0th sublist (column) of the scanned list to see if it is equivalent to any of the items in the neighbour list.

If it is equivalent I want to append both sublists of scanned to the 1st and 2nd sublists of localisation.

I believe this test will check if an item in the 0th sublist in scanned matches any items in the neighbour sublist:

```
for i in scanned[0]:
    for j in neighbour:
        if i == j:
```

but I am not sure how to append both sublists of scanned to the 1st and 2nd sublists of localisation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give an example output?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'd probably structure your lists a different way, but I'll get to that in a minute.

To do what you want to do, you need to iterate in a more old-school way:

```
neighbour = ['a', 'b', 'c']
scanned = [['a', 'b'],[1, 2]]   
localisation = [[],[],[]] 

for i in range(len(scanned[0])):
    if scanned[0][i] in neighbour:
        localisation[1].append(scanned[0][i])
        localisation[2].append(scanned[1][i])
print localisation
>>> [[], ['a', 'b'], [1, 2]]
```

This is assuming I'm (finally) understanding what you want correctly. However, it looks like `scanned` is actually two lists where each element in one list is related somehow to the same-indexed element in the other. Your life would probably be made a fair bit easier by using a `dict` instead:

```
# The keys from the dict are from scanned[0]; the values are from scanned[1]
scanned = {'a':1, 'b':2}
```

Now everything that has to do with these lists is way easier (including whatever else you have to do with them), because you don't have to keep track of your indices separately:

```
neighbour = ['a', 'b', 'c']
scanned = {'a':1, 'b':2}
localisation = [[], [], []] 

for s in scanned:
    if s in neighbour:
        localisation[1].append(s)
        localisation[2].append(scanned[s])

print localisation
>>> [[], ['a', 'b'], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: `localisation[1].append(scanned[1][i])` I think. Correct me if I got it wrong, not sure if I understood the question.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen I think you're right; I'm not positive I know what exactly he wants either. Definitely a typo on my part though.

Comment: Hi I want the 0th sublist of localisation to be declared elsewhere but the rest is exactly what I meant, sorry my post was a bit awkwardly worded - I'm just starting out with python so I'm unsure of all the correct terms.

Comment: @markmcmurray I've rewritten my answer to match up with my current understanding of your question: can you confirm for me that this is correct?

Comment: I think it's the extend one as opposed to the append. If scanned[0][i] appears in neighbour then add scanned[0][i] to localisation[1][k] and add scanned[1][i] to localisation[2][k]

Comment: @markmcmurray OK. For the record, that's still `append`, but only one element. While I go edit my answer to reflect that, it would be great if you could edit your question to be more clear about what you want (an example of correct output would be ideal).

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem related to NLP [Stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)? If so, take a look at Python [NLTK](http://nltk.org/).

To generate a list of matching elements for each sublist in `scanned`:

```
for l in scanned:
    localisation.append(set(l).intersection(neighbour))
```

Your definition is a bit confuse, I'm not sure if I understood what you want. Supposing `len(scanned[0]) == len(scanned[1])`:

```
matches = set(neighbour).intersection(scanned[0])
for match in matches:
    i = scanned.index(match)
    localisation.append((match, scanned[0][i], scanned[1][i]))
```

In this case a dict is better than a list of lists.

```
neighbour = ['Good morning', 'Good afternoon']
scanned = {'Good morning': 'Buenos dias', 'Good night': 'Buenas noches'}
localisation = []

matches = set(neighbour).intersection(scanned.keys())
for match in matches:
    localisation.append((match, scanned[match]))
```

Please provide a sample input and expected output.